# conditional standard handle redirection in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads, io-redirection

I want to read a file, process it, and write the results to another file; the input file name is to be supplied through a console argument, and the output file name is generated from the input file name.

The catch is I want it to transparently “fail over” to stdin/stdout if no arguments are supplied; essentially, in case a file name is supplied, I redirect stdin/stdout to the respective file names so I can transparently use **interact** whether the file name  was supplied or not.

Here's the code hacked together with dummy output in a superfluous **else**. What will be the proper, idiomatic form of doing it?

It probably could have something to do with Control.Monad's  **when** or **guard**, as was pointed out in a similar question, but maybe somebody wrote this already.

```
import System.IO
import Data.Char(toUpper)
import System.Environment
import GHC.IO.Handle

main :: IO ()
main = do
       args <- getArgs
       if(not $ null args) then
        do
           print $ "working with "++ (head args)
           finHandle <- openFile (head args) ReadMode --open the supplied input file
           hDuplicateTo finHandle stdin --bind stdin to finName's handle
           foutHandle <- openFile ((head args) ++ ".out") WriteMode --open the output file for writing
           hDuplicateTo foutHandle stdout --bind stdout to the outgoing file
        else print "working through stdin/redirect" --get to know 
        interact ((++) "Here you go---\n" . map toUpper)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing very special about `interact` - here is its definition:

```
interact        ::  (String -> String) -> IO ()
interact f      =   do s <- getContents
                       putStr (f s)
```

How about something like this:

```
 import System.Environment
 import Data.Char

 main = do
   args <- getArgs
   let (reader, writer) =
        case args of
          []         -> (getContents, putStr)
          (path : _) -> let outpath = path ++ ".output"
                        in (readFile path, writeFile outpath)
   contents <- reader
   writer (process contents)

 process :: String -> String
 process = (++) "Here you go---\n" . map toUpper
```

Based on the command line arguments we set `reader` and `writer` to the IO-actions which will read the input and write the output.

Comment: Thank you very much for desugaring `interact`, should've guessed to do it outright, this code certainly solves the problem at hand, and it is also more portable (`hDuplicateTo` is GHC-specific, it is absent from 2010's Haskell Report).

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly idiomatic to me already. The one note I have is to avoid `head`, as it is an unsafe function (it can throw a runtime error). In this case it is fairly easy to do so by using `case` to pattern match.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    fname:_ -> do
      print $ "working with " ++ fname
      finHandle <- openFile fname ReadMode
      hDuplicateTo finHandle stdin
      foutHandle <- openFile (fname ++ ".out") WriteMode
      hDuplicateTo foutHandle stdout
    [] -> do
      print "working through stdin/redirect"
  interact ((++) "Here you go---\n" . map toUpper)
```

Comment: the 
`print "working through stdin/redirect`
piece is just a kind of **nop** operation to me, the question was on how would I avoid it altogether.